# PHP-Apache. Доступ к картинкам сайта, запрет без регистрации

Tags: php

Есть сайт PHP-Apache с картинками, доступ к которым дается только зарегистрированным пользователям. Этот запрет сейчас реализован через .htaccess -файл, куда на время сессии добавляются разрешенные IP адреса.

Есть ли более удачный вариант реализации доступа к этим картинкам? Вариант с генерацией картинок через скрипт или просто отдачу файла через php-скрипт будет наверно медленной и нагрузной?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычно в таких случаях файл не отдают напрямую, а передают request_uri PHP скрипту, который проверяет наличие доступа к загружаемому файлу, а сам файл физически находится за пределами публичной дериктории web-сервера. 
Для Apache можно применить mod_xsendfile, для Nginx я применял X-Accel-Redirect. 
Можно вообще использовать readfile в PHP, но такой способ отразится на нагрузке на сервер.

Comment: Да, до этого просто делал для залогининых пользователей разрешение на их айпи- адрес. Сейчас попробовал через скрипт- но нагрузка подскочила.  Так что буду ваш вариант смотреть, спс

Comment: К IP адресу вообще не стоит привязываться, т.к. это не уникальный признак, может меняться внутри сессии и даже быть одинаковым у нескольких пользователей. Особенно актуально для небольших поселков и городов.

Comment: Mod-xsendfile то что надо, спс

Answer (score -1):

Ну будет немного медленнее, но на сколько я понял вашу задачу, вам больше подойдёт возвращать картинку php скриптом. Три варианта:

1. Запретить через htaccess файл доступ к директории (всем, но только возможность просмотреть содержимое директории) и пусть скрипт проверяет залогинен ли пользователь, и если да, то отдает прямой путь к картинке
2. Сделать первый вариант, только заменить htaccess, просто поместив в корень каталога с картинками файл index.php с редиректом или тп.
3. Самое удачное решение на мой взгляд - хранить картинки в бд в виде base64 и отдавать скриптом с проверкой пользователя на логин.

Comment: У этого проекта будет большая нагрузка,... не рухнет ли все при скрипте?    например как facebook это делает?

Comment: Ну если большая нагрузка то и сервак наверное будет "большим") Так, что не думаю

Comment: Спс, буду пробовать скриптовый вариант.

Comment: У варианта с отдачей через readfile слишком большая нагрузку буду пробовать совет ниже.